# how to use go-swagger with sentry performance monitoring?

Tags: performance, go, sentry, open-telemetry, go-swagger

i am using [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger) .
Sentry added [perormance monitoring](https://docs.sentry.io/product/performance/) i am looking for best pratice to add this feature in my project.

I know, go-swagger uses "net/http" but it is still a liitle bit controversial about correct way to adding.
I added init sentry into configure_myapp_api.go

```golang
func InitSentry(cfg *configs.Config) {
    err := sentry.Init(sentry.ClientOptions{
        Dsn:              cfg.SentryDsn,
        Environment:      fmt.Sprintf("[%s][%s]", "myapp-api-back", cfg.SentryEnvironment),
        AttachStacktrace: true,
        TracesSampleRate: 0.2,
        SampleRate:       0.2,
        EnableTracing:    true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Sentry initialization failed: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer sentry.Recover()
}
```

Should it be just a middleware?